# How do I find the name of an operating system?

Tags: c++, operating-system

The questions pretty simple. I want want a function (C++) or method which will, on call, returun something like

```
"Windows" //or
"Unix"
```

Nothing fancy, I dont need the version numbe or anything. Just the os name. A quick google searc didnt turn up anything useful, so I thought I'd post this here

Comment: There's no universal solution, as already noted.  Qt added `QSysInfo` for precisely that reason.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Since you can not have a single binary file which runs over all operating systems, and you need to re-compile your code again. It's OK to use MACROs.

Use macros such as

```
_WIN32
_WIN64
__unix
__unix__
__APPLE__
__MACH__
__linux__
__FreeBSD__
```

like this

```
std::string getOsName()
{
    #ifdef _WIN32
    return "Windows 32-bit";
    #elif _WIN64
    return "Windows 64-bit";
    #elif __APPLE__ || __MACH__
    return "Mac OSX";
    #elif __linux__
    return "Linux";
    #elif __FreeBSD__
    return "FreeBSD";
    #elif __unix || __unix__
    return "Unix";
    #else
    return "Other";
    #endif
}
```

*You should read compiler's manuals and see what MACROS they provided to detect the OS on compile time.*

Comment: I downvoted, because this is reinventing the wheel in a non-portable way.

Comment: @H2CO3 under what C++ compiler/OS would this fail to compile?  Isn't code portability measured by its ability to be compiled with any compliant compiler on any OS?

Comment: @MerickOWA "in a non-portable way": the macros M. M. uses are not defined neither in the C nor in the C++ standard. "Reinventing the wheel": the code replicates functionality present in the standard library.

Comment: @H2CO3 which standard library? the C++ standard library doesn't define a uname function.

Comment: Look to my comment below with citation from GNU documentation. I don't recommend to use system specific internal macros in application code.

Comment: Not reliable. Can report WINE as Windows, FreeBSD as Linux.

Comment: You can expand this approach; if you need a comprehensive solution, have a look at https://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/OperatingSystems/

Comment: Thank you. I believe UNIX should be the last one -- it wrongly reported as Unix when in Linux...

Comment: If you compile for Linux, then run the exact same binary on Windows (using WSL), it will give you the wrong OS name.

Comment: @Brendan: You're right; but what is the correct answer when the code is running on Wine? From code's point of view, depending on the actual problem, either Windows or Linux could be correct.

Answer (score 4):

From the Poco source code:

Win32:

```
std::string EnvironmentImpl::osNameImpl()
{
    OSVERSIONINFO vi;
    vi.dwOSVersionInfoSize = sizeof(vi);
    if (GetVersionEx(&vi) == 0) throw SystemException("Cannot get OS version information");
    switch (vi.dwPlatformId)
    {
    case VER_PLATFORM_WIN32s:
        return "Windows 3.x";
    case VER_PLATFORM_WIN32_WINDOWS:
        return vi.dwMinorVersion == 0 ? "Windows 95" : "Windows 98";
    case VER_PLATFORM_WIN32_NT:
        return "Windows NT";
    default:
        return "Unknown";
    }
}
```

Unix:

```
std::string EnvironmentImpl::osNameImpl()
{
    struct utsname uts;
    uname(&uts);
    return uts.sysname;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't give a single cross-platform implementation to distinguish the OS between eg windows and linux, but two platform-dependent implementations to tell the version of the OS that require you to already know whether you have windows or linux.