# How to detect current operating system at runtime in c++?

Tags: c++, windows, macos, operating-system

I want to detect which operating system my .exe is being run on, so that I could perform specific operations depending on the underlying operating system. I want it to be just for windows and mac.

Comment: Considering that executable programs are targeted at a specific hardware *and* operating system platform, there's really no need to do it at run-time. Doing it at compile-time (through conditional compilation with the preprocessor) is often enough.

Comment: you can't even launch the executable if you aren't on the right OS

Comment: Your exe file won't run on OS X and OS X executable won't run on Windows. So there's no way to do it. You can however target platform specific code when compiling your app

Comment: how to do it through conditional_compilation? @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: Please clarify: are you trying to distinguish whether you're running on Windows or Mac? If so, that should be done at compile time, since the executables have to be compiled differently. Or are you trying to distinguish e.g. Windows 7 vs. Windows 10? That would have to be a run-time query.

Comment: Out of interest, what are you wanting to do? I'm thinking in terms of having a component like Boost deal with the platform-specific stuff for you.

Comment: I think this depends on your build tools. WIth CMake you can set a variable depending on your OS. In your code you can use `#ifdef WINDOWS` or `#ifdef MACOS`. Which build tools do you use?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15580179/how-do-i-find-the-name-of-an-operating-system

Answer (score 1):

> I want to detect which operating system my .exe is being run on

(notice that on MacOSX executable files are traditionally not suffixed with `.exe`; that convention is specific to Windows)

**You cannot detect that in *pure* standard C++11 at runtime** (so your question makes technically no sense), because the C++11 standard [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) does not know about operating systems (some C++ source code may be compiled for the bare metal). I would recommend conditional compilation (e.g. `#if`) and using operating system specific headers (and configuring your [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) to detect them). Some C++ frameworks ([boost](https://www.boost.org/), [poco](https://pocoproject.org/), [Qt](http://qt.io/)....) could be helpful, but you need to decide to choose one (they might try to provide some common [abstractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction_(computer_science)) above several OSes, but the evil is still in the details, e.g. file paths are still different on Windows and on MacOSX).

[MicroSoft Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows) has its own [API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface), called [WinAPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_API) (which is only, in practice, used by Windows. Perhaps some day [ReactOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReactOS) would implement most of that API), documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/apiindex/windows-api-list). [MacOSX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS) is more or less conforming to [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX), which is a standard API about a family of OSes (but Windows don't care much about that standard).

If you want to learn more about OSes in general (a sensible thing to do), read for example [*Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) (freely downloadable textbook).

In practice, an [executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable) file compiled from C++ source code is specific to the operating system it is designed to run on, and its file format is also [specific](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_executable_file_formats) to some OS (e.g. [PE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable) on Windows, [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) on Linux, [Mach-O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mach-O) on MacOSX...). So a Windows executable won't run on MacOSX and vice versa (the [fat binary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fat_binary) idea is out of fashion in 2018). You probably would adjust your [build](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_build) procedure (e.g. your [`Makefile`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makefile), or with [cmake](https://cmake.org/), [ninja](http://ninja-build.org/), etc...) for your OS. That build procedure might (and often does) pass extra compilation flags (e.g. some `-DBUILD_FOR_MACOSX` compiler [flag for your preprocessor](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html), if building for MacOSX; then you might -in few places- use  some preprocessor directive like `#if BUILD_FOR_MACOSX` in your C++ source code) specific to the target operating system. You could even customize your build so that on MacOSX some `for-macosx.cc` C++ file is compiled (and its object file linked into) your software, but on Windows you'll use some other `for_windows.cc` C++ file. Sometimes, the build procedure is flexible enough to auto-detect at build time what is the operating system (but how to do that is a different question. The GNU [autoconf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoconf) could be inspirational).

Once your build procedure has been configured for (or has auto-detected) your operating system, you could use preprocessor [conditional facilities](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Conditionals.html) to `#include` appropriate system-specific headers and to compile calls to OS specific functions (such as POSIX [uname](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/uname.html)) querying further at runtime about the OS.

Some compilers predefine a set of preprocessor symbols, and that set depends upon the target operating system and processor and of your compiler. If you use [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), you might create some *empty* file `empty.cc` and compile it with `g++ -c -C -E -dM` (perhaps also with other relevant flags, e.g. `-std=c++11`) to find out which set of preprocessor symbols are predefined in your case.

Consider studying the source code (including the build procedure!) of some cross-platform [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) projects (e.g. on [github](http://github.com/) or somewhere else) for inspiration. You can also find many resources about multi-platform C++ builds (e.g. [this](http://cs-courses.mines.edu/csci262/spring2018/resources/guide.pdf) one and *many* others).

Comment: Explaining why not is not what was asked. It's explaining how to, and if it's not possible at runtime, then explain how to do it at compile time. This is a lot of text with a lot of links that nobody reads simply because it's not a solution but an explanation why his question makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways you could do it, like testing for the presence of a C:\Windows directory to detect Windows (edit: if the OS accepts a path like that at all then it's at least part of the DOS family), but none of them are foolproof. Here's one way (although it's cheating):

```
#include<boost/predef.h>

enum class OperatingSystem {
// ...
Windows
// ...
};

OperatingSystem DetectOperatingSystem()
{
#ifdef BOOST_OS_WINDOWS
return OperatingSystem::Windows;
#endif
}
```

Also, if you just want a name to show the user, then on POSIX systems you can use uname(2).

Comment: Not even Windows guarantees the presence of `C:\Windows`.

Comment: the issue remain that the ABI is different between OS, that the system calls are different, that the file paths are different ...

Comment: You technically *could* have a path like `C:\Windows` on Linux or most other Unixes, but that is very weird and against common conventions. BTW, you could even have a file on Linux named with a single newline character, but that is weird. You can't be sure that `C:\Windows` is the signature of windows systems.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Also, the user could be on Linux and have them installed on the same partition (e.g. used Wubi for the Linux installation), so then you literally would have C:\Windows even though you'd be on the Linux environment.

Comment: Are you sure? I would imagine that the Linux system would see something like `//C/Windows` corresponding to what Windows see as `C:\Windows` . But I don't know what Wubi is (just discovered that it is *not* a Linux ELF executable). My point is that on my Linux laptop, I can write a C program running `mkdir("C:\\Windows", 0750);` Then some later `opendir("C:\\Windows")` would succeed (inside some other C program). Ok, it is wicked, but technically allowed. So you cannot be sure that `opendir("C:\\Windows")` success means that you are on Windows.

Comment: Well, I have written there, for testing the presence of C:\Windows directory to detect the presence of windows.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this kind of problem you would need to check both at compile time and at run time. You are going to need different code for different both systems. You are going to need Windoze code to check the Windoze version and Mac code to check the Mac version.

You are going to have to use

```
#if defined ()
```

at compile time to check which of the two you are on. Then have separate code for each to get the version.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use `argv[0]` which is path to your executable being ran and then:

1. Open this as a file;
2. Read first couple of bytes of this file (the magic number);
3. Determine the OS based on magic bytes:

   - `M` `Z` *(Windows PE)*
   - `0x7f` `E` `L` `F` *(Linux ELF)*
   - ...

This should work if the binary is not a raw binary, which means that magic number says `data`. This could deceive you if executable was cross-compiled for some other system. On Linux you can check the magic bytes with command:

```
file <your executable>
```

Comment: Why would anybody use this instead of `#ifdef` at compile-time?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat If you disslike `#ifdef` blocks...